# Transaction handling when wrapping Stream into Flux

Tags: java, transactions, spring-data-jpa, java-stream, project-reactor

I really have issues understanding what's going on behind the sences when manually wrapping `Stream` received as a query result from spring data jpa into a `Flux`.

Consider the following:

Entity:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
public class TestEntity {
    @Id
    private Integer a;
    private Integer b;
}
```

Repository:

```
public interface TestEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<TestEntity, Integer> {
    Stream<TestEntity> findByBBetween(int b1, int b2);
}
```

Simple test code:

```
@Test
@SneakyThrows
@Transactional
public void dbStreamToFluxTest() {
    testEntityRepository.save(new TestEntity(2, 6));
    testEntityRepository.save(new TestEntity(3, 8));
    testEntityRepository.save(new TestEntity(4, 10));

    testEntityFlux(testEntityStream()).subscribe(System.out::println);
    testEntityFlux().subscribe(System.out::println);
    Thread.sleep(200);
}

private Flux<TestEntity> testEntityFlux() {
    return fromStream(this::testEntityStream);
}

private Flux<TestEntity> testEntityFlux(Stream<TestEntity> testEntityStream) {
    return fromStream(() -> testEntityStream);
}

private Stream<TestEntity> testEntityStream() {
    return testEntityRepository.findByBBetween(1, 9);
}

static <T> Flux<T> fromStream(final Supplier<Stream<? extends T>> streamSupplier) {
    return Flux
            .defer(() -> Flux.fromStream(streamSupplier))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic());
}
```

Questions:

1. Is this the correct way to do what I do, especially regarding the static `fromStream` method?
2. While the call to `testEntityFlux(testEntityStream())` does what I expect, for reasons I really don't understand, the call to `testEntityFlux()` runs into an error:

> reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: You're trying to execute a streaming query method without a surrounding transaction that keeps the connection open so that the Stream can actually be consumed. Make sure the code consuming the stream uses @Transactional or any other way of declaring a (read-only) transaction.
>   Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: You're trying to execute a streaming query method without a surrounding transaction that keeps the connection open so that the Stream can actually be consumed. Make sure the code consuming the stream uses @Transactional or any other way of declaring a (read-only) transaction.

... what usually happens when I forget the @Transactional, which I didn't.

**EDIT**

Note: The code was inspired by: https://github.com/chang-chao/spring-webflux-reactive-jdbc-sample/blob/master/src/main/java/me/changchao/spring/springwebfluxasyncjdbcsample/service/CityServiceImpl.java which in turn was inspired by https://spring.io/blog/2016/07/20/notes-on-reactive-programming-part-iii-a-simple-http-server-application.
However, the `Mono` version has the same "issue".

**EDIT 2**

An example using optional, note that in `testEntityMono()` replacing `testEntityOptional()` with `testEntityOptionalManual()` leads to working code. Thus it all seems to be directly related to how jpa does the data fetching:

```
@SneakyThrows
@Transactional
public void dbOptionalToMonoTest() {
    testEntityRepository.save(new TestEntity(2, 6));
    testEntityRepository.save(new TestEntity(3, 8));
    testEntityRepository.save(new TestEntity(4, 10));

    testEntityMono(testEntityOptional()).subscribe(System.out::println);
    testEntityMono().subscribe(System.out::println);

    Thread.sleep(1200);
}

private Mono<TestEntity> testEntityMono() {
    return fromSingle(() -> testEntityOptional().get());
}

private Mono<TestEntity> testEntityMono(Optional<TestEntity> testEntity) {
    return fromSingle(() -> testEntity.get());
}

private Optional<TestEntity> testEntityOptional() {
    return testEntityRepository.findById(4);
}

@SneakyThrows
private Optional<TestEntity> testEntityOptionalManual() {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    return Optional.of(new TestEntity(20, 20));
}

static <T> Mono<T> fromSingle(final Supplier<T> tSupplier) {
    return Mono
            .defer(() -> Mono.fromSupplier(tSupplier))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic());
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### TL;DR:

It boils down to the differences between imperative and reactive programming assumptions and `Thread` affinity.

### Details

We first need to understand what happens with transaction management to understand why your arrangement ends with a failure.

Using a `@Transactional` method creates a transactional scope for all code within the method. Transactional methods returning scalar values, `Stream`, collection-like types, or `void` (basically non-reactive types) are considered imperative transactional methods.

In imperative programming, flows stick to their carrier `Thread`. The code is expected to remain on the same `Thread` and not to switch threads. Therefore, transaction management associates transactional state and resources with the carrier `Thread` in a `ThreadLocal` storage. As soon as code within a transactional method switches threads (e.g. spinning up a new `Thread` or using a `Thread` pool), the unit of work that gets executed on a different `Thread` leaves the transactional scope and potentially runs in its own transaction. In the worst case, the transaction is left open on an external `Thread` because there is no transaction manager monitoring entry/exit of the transactional unit of work.

`@Transactional` methods returning a reactive type (such as `Mono` or `Flux`) are subject to reactive transaction management. Reactive transaction management is different from imperative transaction management as the transactional state is attached to a `Subscription`, specifically the subscriber `Context`. The context is only available with reactive types, not with scalar types as there are no means to attach data to `void` or a `String`.

Looking at the code:

```
@Test
@Transactional
public void dbStreamToFluxTest() {
    // …
}
```

we see that this method is a `@Transactional` test method. Here we have two things to consider:

1. The method returns `void` so it is subject to imperative transaction management associating the transactional state with a `ThreadLocal`.
2. There's no reactive transaction support for `@Test` methods because typically a `Publisher` is expected to be returned from the method, and by doing so, there would be no way to assert the outcome of the stream.

   ```
   @Test
   @Transactional
   public Publisher<Object> thisDoesNotWork() {
       return myRepository.findAll(); // Where did my assertions go?
   }
   ```

Let's take a closer look at the `fromStream(…)` method:

```
static <T> Flux<T> fromStream(final Supplier<Stream<? extends T>> streamSupplier) {
    return Flux
        .defer(() -> Flux.fromStream(streamSupplier))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic());
}
```

The code accepts a `Supplier` that returns a `Stream`. Next, subscription (`subscribe(…)`, `request(…)`) signals are instructed to happen on the elastic `Scheduler` which effectively switches on which `Thread` the `Stream` gets created and consumed. Therefore, `subscribeOn` causes the `Stream` creation (call to `findByBBetween(…)`) to happen on a different `Thread` than your carrier `Thread`.

Removing `subscribeOn(…)` will fix your issue.

There is a bit more to explain why you want to refrain from using reactive types with JPA. Reactive programming has no strong `Thread` affinity. `Thread` switching may occur at any time. Depending on how you use the resulting `Flux` and how you have designed your entities, you might experience visibility issues as entities are passed across threads. Ideally, data in a reactive context remains immutable. Such an approach does not always comply with JPA rules.

Another aspect is lazy loading. By using JPA entities from threads other than the carrier `Thread`, the entity may not be able to correlate its context back to the JPA Transaction. You can easily run into `LazyInitializationException` without being aware of why this is as `Thread` switching can be opaque to you.

The recommendation is: Do not use reactive types with JPA or any other transactional resources. Stay with Java 8 `Stream` instead.

Comment: Ok, thus the ` testEntityMono(testEntityOptional()).subscribe(System.out::println);` only works since the stream is consumed within the calling thread and `subscribeOn(...)` is quite useless here. However, the idea behind all that is to be able to serve many requests without blocking the listening thread. Thus, I wanted to do the slow database call in another thread.

Answer (score 1):

The Stream returned by the repository is lazy. It uses the connection to the database in order to get the rows when the stream is being consumed by a terminal operation.

The connection is bound to the current transaction, and the current transaction is stored in a ThreadLocal variable, i.e. is bound to the thread that is eecuting your test method.

But the consumption of the stream is done on a separate thread, belonging to the thread pool used by the elastic scheduler of Reactor. So you create the lazy stream on the main thread, which has the transaction bound to it, but you consume the stream on a separate thread, which doesn't have the transaction bound to it.

Don't use reactor with JPA transactions and entities. They're incompatible.